# Equivalent np.nanquantile in Julia?

Tags: arrays, numpy, statistics, julia

Is there a `np.nanquantile` equivalent in Julia? I have a 2D array and calculate a quantile along one axis but the array contains `NaN`-values. My current code block:

```
quantiles = Array{Float32}(undef, size(array, 1), 2)
p=0.1
quantiles[:, 1] = mapslices(x -> quantile(x, p), array, dims = 2)
quantiles[:, 2] = mapslices(x -> quantile(x, 1 - p), array, dims = 2)
```

Comment: Please confirm if you have `NaN` or `missing` values in your data (as this affects the answer). How did you get `NaN` values in your `array`?

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński I have ```NaN``` values, they are from Python calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to use the following:

```
x -> quantile(filter(!isnan, x), p)
```

e.g.

```
julia> array = [1   NaN 3 4
                NaN 2   3 4]
2×4 Matrix{Float64}:
   1.0  NaN    3.0  4.0
 NaN      2.0  3.0  4.0

julia> mapslices(x -> quantile(filter(!isnan, x), 0.5), array, dims = 2)
2×1 Matrix{Float64}:
 3.0
 3.0
```